# Column not found when running unit tests in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, spring-boot-test

I have this problem when testing a JPA repository:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "CREATED_AT" not found; SQL statement:
        insert into people_establishments (created_at, establishment_id, person_id, updated_at) values (?, ?, ?, ?) [42122-212]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
        at org.h2.table.Table.getColumn(Table.java:754)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumn(Parser.java:1264)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnList(Parser.java:1249)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1650)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:814)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:691)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:568)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:1044)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
        ... 139 more
```

But this column exist in this entity file:

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "people_establishments")
public class PersonEstablishment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "establishment_id")
    private Integer establishmentId;

    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Integer personId;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private OffsetDateTime updatedAt;

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void updateDateFields() {
        if (this.createdAt == null) {
            this.createdAt = OffsetDateTime.now();
        }

        this.updatedAt = OffsetDateTime.now();
    }

}
```

Test method:

```
@DataJpaTest
class PersonRepositoryTest extends EntitiesFactory {
    
    // ...
    
    @Autowired
    protected PeopleEstablishmentsRepository peopleEstablishmentsRepository;

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        peopleRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void itShouldFindPersonByIdAndEstablishmentIdCreatedBy() {
        // given
        int createdBy = 1;

        Establishment e = createEstablishment("Restaurant", createdBy);
        Person p = createPerson("John", createdBy);

        PersonEstablishment personEstablishment = PersonEstablishment.builder()
                .personId(p.getId())
                .establishmentId(e.getId())
                .build();

        // The error is happenig here
        peopleEstablishmentsRepository.save(personEstablishment);

        // when
        Optional<Person> expected = peopleRepository.findByIdAndEstablishmentIdCreatedBy(p.getId(), e.getId(), createdBy);

        // then
        assertThat(expected).isPresent();
    }

    // ...
    
}
```

I am using h2 database to run the test, and I have other similar tables and they are working, only this one is failing, I tried to check the name if I have a typo, but the name is correct. Do you know what could be happening?

EDIT:

I found the error, the relation between Establishment and PeopleEstablishments wasn't set correctly. I deleted this relationship and it works:

```
public class Establishment {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(schema = "public", name = "people_establishments",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "establishment_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private List<Person> people;

    ...

}
```

Comment: It literally says column = "created_at" was not found. Did you check you database? You sure it exists?

Comment: @Vusal It is working fine when I start the project ( I am using liquibase to create the tables and the MySQL database ). The problem is happening only during unit tests

Comment: I know, I am using the h2 to run the tests in a memory database

Comment: This is what I want to know, why the h2 doesn't have this column, I defined it in the Entity class.
I have another class that is similar to this one and works